# how to update email field to NULL value using data loader

Tags: data-loader

I have a field email TL1 which have values populated by a workflow. Also I want to make this field as blank using NULL value in data loader. I have changed the setting of data loader "Insert null values". Still I am not able to change value to null. I have also tried to deactivate the workflow and tried still no success.

I am getting the error in data loader as "Invalid email address :NULL".

Comment: Are you using the word literal "null" or just have the value blank?

Comment: Have you tried "" (empty string)?

Comment: I am getting the same error @Jagular

Comment: @Girbot: I am using the word null

Comment: If the field type is email, then you can't update it to value "null" because that is not valid email address. May be you can change the field type from email to text and then update the values to empty string and then change the field type back to email.

Comment: @javanoob: I think data would be lost for other records which I change field data type

Comment: You won't lose data if you change email field to text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have already changed the setting of data loader `"Insert null values"`.
so, in the .csv, email field will be blank. **NO quotes**, **NO NULL word**.

If you open the .csv in notepad or notepad++, it will show values like this where email and phone are showing blank:

> NAME,EMAIL__C,Phone
>
> Jup20,,

You should successfully load the data.

Comment: I tried with the above method but it did not get updated may be since the fields are pre filled by a workflow

Comment: pre filled by a workflow means? and with which values?

Comment: @kunalgupta But In the post you mentioned that you deactivated the workflow?